# Task hierarchy in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-office, tasks, microsoft-outlook

Is there any way (possibly through external add-ins) to organize tasks in hierarchy (with tasks and subtasks) in Microsoft Outlook? What I need is something similar to [this SharePoint Web Part](http://www.teamdirection.com/igwebpart/index.html).

Comment: Does https://to-do.live.com/tasks/ provide what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I use [Taskline](http://www.taskline.com/), which does exactly that.  It has not yet been updated for Outlook 2010's ribbon interface, but it still works okay.  It's takes a little effort to figure out.

I cannot think why Microsoft has not added this functionality to Outlook yet, other than to push Microsoft Project.